# How to implement CSRF protection for user identification without login in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, single-page-application

I'm developing an app like anonymous bulletin board.

The app is configured react and django rest framework.

To identify user by cookie of uuid, I use custom middleware like this

```
import uuid
from django.contrib.sessions.middleware import SessionMiddleware
from django.http.request import HttpRequest
from django.http.response import HttpResponse


class CustomMiddleware(SessionMiddleware):
    def process_response(self, request: HttpRequest, response: HttpResponse) -> HttpResponse:
        user_id = request.COOKIES.get('user_id', None)
        if not user_id:
            max_age = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60
            response.set_cookie(
                'user_id',
                str(uuid.uuid4()),
                max_age=max_age,
                samesite='lax'
            )
        return super().process_response(request, response)
```

Then I googled how to protect the app from CSRF and couldn't find it.

Please teach me the best way of it.

regards.

I tried to use session and csrf token, but I hovent any idea.

I don't know how to store the csrf token on the server and verify that it matches.

Answer (score 1):

to protect you app from CSRF attacks you can use Django's built-in CSRF protection middleware. this middleware checks for a special token in each POST request. this token is required to be sent with any POST request for the request to be accepted.

make sure that you have `CsrfViewMiddleware` in your settings.py MIDDLEWARE section

`'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',`

if you want to exempt any views from CSRF protection you can use the `@csrf_exemp` decorator:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exemp
def your_view(request):
    pass
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I don't think it will work cuz csrf_exemp in the drf view is set to true by default.

Do u know the way of using session and csrf token?

Comment: I don't know how to store the csrf token on the server and verify that it matches.